# Replacing all instances of a value in JSON using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible using JavaScript only to replace all instances of the version with another number and then return the JSON structure intact?

```
{
    "savedSearches": [{
        "id": 123,
        "version": 10,
        "name": "Project Manager",
        "query": "www.foo.com"
    }, {
        "id": 123,
        "version": 10,
        "name": "Project Manager",
        "query": "www.foo.com"
    }],
    "deletedSavedSearches": []
}
```

I need this to be very quick and lightweight as I'll be using it within JMeter.

Comment: Do you have this parsed in an object? or is it a string?

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "JSON Structure" - it's just a JavaScript object. You just need to iterate through the values of the "savedSearches" array and change the "version" properties however you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(yourJSONString);

for(var i = 0, len = jsonObject.savedSearches.length; i < len; i++) {
    jsonObject.savedSearches[i].version = "Number you want here";
}
```

If you, for some reason, want to return a string:

```
JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
```

If you already have the object, you can skip the `JSON.parse`

Comment: For a possible modest speed improvement with a large number of items, add `var searches = jsonObject.savedSearches;` and replace `jsonObject.savedSearches` with `searches` in the rest of the code. (In the latest optimizing compilers it may not matter, but it never hurts.)

Answer (score 3):

JSON structure is nothing more than a JavaScript object. You can iterate over its properties and modify their values as usual. For instance, to increase each `version` by one:

```
var json = { … }
for (var i in json.savedSearches) json.savedSearches[i].version += 1;
```